# jsonb will not be updated if I add a field

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa, jsonb

With this code, Hibernate does not execute an update statement

```
MyEntitity entity;
entity.getJSONB().put("Field", 14f); //returns Map<String,Object>
session.merge(entity);
```

this works:

```
MyEntitity entity;
entity.setX(12);
entity.getJSONB().put("Field", 14f); //returns Map<String,Object>
session.merge(entity);
```

and this works as well:

```
MyEntitity entity;
HashMap<String, Object> newMap = new HashMap<String, Object>(entity.getJSONB());
newMap.put("Field", 14f);
entitiy.setJSONB(newMap);
session.merge(entity);
```

so If I ONLY modify the existing object it does not lead to an update command.

I guess this is a bug, but maybe there is a better workaround?

Comment: Your JSON object reference has stayed the same, and JPA providers mostly treat basic mappings as immutable (int/string etc can't be changed, you have to create a new instance) so the change isn't detected. Call setJSONB with a new JSON object and it'll pick up the difference. Hibernate might have other ways to specify this property is mutable and to detect changes to it, but like with dates  and other wrapper classes where the value can change, it is a performance benefit to not bother trying to detect those changes and require a new instance.

Comment: @Chris Is there a way to make the JSON content mutable? Do you have a link supporting your statement for further reading? Thank you!

Comment: I'm more familiar with EclipseLink which addes the Mutable annotation for similar reasons (https://stackoverflow.com/a/71146971/496099 and https://eclipse.dev/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/a_mutable.htm#:~:text=Use%20%40Mutable%20on%20a%20%40Basic,weaved%20with%20non%2Dmutable%20mappings ) and JPA specification makes various references to mutable mappings in ways I don't remember, but not ways of changing it (behavior is just undefined from what I remember). I'm not sure what hibernate might have to workaround it.